# Android MediaRecorder/Player Either Not Recording or Not Playing

Tags: java, android, audio

Hello I'm having difficulty getting simple audio capture to work (record and then play back). I took the example code from the Android Developer's Audio Capture page and I can run the code on my phone and press start/stop record and start/stop play. No errors are thrown, so I'm not sure where to begin with debugging this. One empirical thing I did notice (perhaps a useless fact) is when I press play a ringing sound does emanate from the mic.

The device I am using to test is the Galaxy Nexus, version 4.2.2.

I'll post the code from the Android Developer's Site so that it can be easily referenced. I have tried a few things, but nothing really pointed me in a direction any closer to answering the issue. Thanks.

```
/*
 * The application needs to have the permission to write to external storage
 * if the output file is written to the external storage, and also the
 * permission to record audio. These permissions must be set in the
 * application's AndroidManifest.xml file, with something like:
 *
 * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 * <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 *
 */
package com.android.audiorecordtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import java.io.IOException;


public class AudioRecordTest extends Activity
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    public AudioRecordTest() {
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move 2 lines which initialise mFileName variable from the constructor to onCreate():

```
public AudioRecordTest() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    //initialise the path here
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";

    //rest of the code
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. On an additional note, why does the Activity constructor fail to initialize mFileName correctly? But I guess I'll be more mindful of preferring OnCreate() to Activity constructors now.

Comment: Hmm well now I changed the code back to the way it was and that works now. The only difference, I think, from my previous attempts is that I had plugged and unplugged the phone from the computer. Just noting it, just in case someone else has similar (seeming) issues.

Comment: It might be the reason, the docs say: "This directory may not currently be accessible if it has been mounted by the user on their computer" - so your mFileName might have been not initialised properly.

Answer (score 0):

do you have add the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
```

Comment: Yes I added the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

download this simple proejct ,it Running perfectly :
http://www.mediafire.com/download/fml2gr2ulzgk22u/AudioRecorder.2.rar