# Audio Recording not heard on Android

Tags: android, playback, voice, recording, genymotion

I want to record voice on Android. I am using a sample code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) from Google samples. I can see the sample creating a file on SDCard on recording. However, when I trying to play the same again on GenyMotion, I do not hear any recording.

Any pointers will be a big help. Anyone else had similar issues.

On further research, I found a exact same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160130/android-mediarecorder-player-either-not-recording-or-not-playing) but the solution provided does not work.

I copied the output file on PC and tried playing it. However there is no recording. It means that recording is not working.

Comment: Did you try on a real device?

Comment: It would not surprise me if audio on an emulator was zeroed, though perhaps there's a configuration option to substitute some real input or output device.  In general terms, emulator are far inferior to actual devices for development, and doubly so when media is concerned.  But you could instrument your code to see if you are getting non-zero audio data.

Comment: _"I copied the output file on PC and tried playing it. However there is no recording. It means that recording is not working."_ Not necessarily. That example you linked to appears to be recording using an AMR-NB encoder and 3GPP container. While these are common on mobile phones, far from all PC media players support them.

Answer (score 0):

Recording on Genymotion doesn't work under Windows.

Comment: Is there any way to test on Emulator or only real device will work. Samsung Galaxy model I have also is not compatible with Win-8.0. Any way of testing it will be help. I played on PC using 3GP player @Michael

Comment: You could use genymotion on a mac or linux, it will works. There is no way to make it works under windows at this time.